# Custom react hook not updating it's value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I have the following custom hook, I want to use it to enable/disable some buttons based on various triggers inside the app.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

interface IDisableProps {
  buttonsDisabled: boolean;
  toggleButtons: (isDisabled: boolean) => void;
}

export default function useDisable(): IDisableProps {
  const [buttonsDisabled, setButtonsDisabled] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const toggleButtons = (isDisabled: boolean) => {
    setButtonsDisabled(isDisabled);
  };

  return {
    buttonsDisabled,
    toggleButtons,
  };
}
```

One of the places I'm using it from is another hook, where I declare it as

`const { buttonsDisabled, toggleButtons } = useDisable();` then use it at the right moment like

```
if (!buttonsDisabled) {
  toggleButtons(true);
}
```

However, the state always remains the initial one. Upon entering with debugger in `toggleButtons` I see that in the local scope, `this` is undefined and can't see the value of `buttonsDisabled`. What am I missing here? Did I take the wrong approach?

Comment: You might need to use `useRef` for `toggleButton` function to get the hang of the reference of memory for that function.

Comment: You have to understand that the debugger global state 'this' on chrome does bind well with the compiled React code. What are you using to debug this? There are some great articles about this topic - [React Debugging](https://flaviocopes.com/react-debugging/). I have also tested your code in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-hill-zdbeb?file=/src/App.js) seems fine to me

Comment: @mjabadilla Thanks for the suggestion, I've been using `debugger` to stop inside `toggleButton()`

Comment: If you really want, try to drill down on the global state and look for the object instances you want. Often they have similar names but not exact. There are also options to debug your code in editor like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=viI7m8UREvw) but it may outdated and very hard for other configurations. The easiest is just simply console.log for simple things and walk your way through the more advanced stuff once you get a hold of the runtime nitty-gritty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Building Your Own Hooks – React](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html)

> **Do two components using the same Hook share state?** No. Custom Hooks are a mechanism to reuse stateful logic (such as setting up a subscription and remembering the current value), but every time you use a custom Hook, all state and effects inside of it are fully isolated.

So when you say "one of the places [you're] using it from is another hook" you are creating an additional `[buttonsDisabled, setButtonsDisabled]` in memory and not referencing the same state created in the other place(s) you've invoked `useDisable`.

Two ways to share state are 1) passing props around and 2) using [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Answer (score -1):

try with

```
const toggleButtons = useMemo(isDisabled: boolean) => {
    setButtonsDisabled(isDisabled)
}, [isDisabled]);
```

Comment: You forgot a parenthesis when opening useMemo but I don't see how this hook would help in this case, it's not a performance issue, at least not right now. Also, adding the parameter the function receives int he watch array seems odd.